# Share certificates in GitHub actions

Tags: github-actions

I am trying to create a certificate from a bash script, which is executed from my workflow (GitHub actions). The file is supposed to be stored in the helm charts, which are used for deployment to Azure Kubernetes. In the deployment, the file is used.

My problem is the workflow keeps failing, the different steps are within the same job, where is the file stored if in the script I give the GitHub repository? Or how could I temporarily save the file for the deployment? It is configured to be mounted on the helm charts but it fails to start.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Do you really need to create a new certificate on-the-fly every time the action is executed? If no, you can use secrets to store a dedicated certificate and then read it during execution, https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets

Comment: Unfortunately yes, it's a requirement from the company, but thank you anyways!

Answer (score 0):

You can send the certificate created in one job to another using [upload-artifact](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact) and [download-artifact](https://github.com/actions/download-artifact).

Uploading a file `world.txt`

```
steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v3

- run: mkdir -p path/to/artifact

- run: echo hello > path/to/artifact/world.txt

- uses: actions/upload-artifact@latest
  with:
    name: my-artifact
    path: path/to/artifact/world.txt
```

and downloading a file

```
steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@master

- uses: actions/download-artifact@latest
  with:
    name: my-artifact
    path: path/to/artifact
    
- run: cat path/to/artifact/world.txt
```

If you don't want to store old certificates, delete them with [delete-artifact](https://github.com/jimschubert/delete-artifacts-action).

OP said that they want to make a certificate and use it in the same step, but this is bad practice. Creating certificates and helm should be in different jobs (possibly stages if that makes logical sense for your setup).

They can also be made into a [reusable workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows) if these are required again.